# Make the page wait until it loads the second time

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I have a site I need to log in and then change the URL. After it loads copy the entire site to excel.
If I'm doing it slowly (<kbd>F8</kbd> button) or do application wait function, it work but its not optimal for different PC, and if I set it too high the data will take forever to load.

I wrote this code:

```
Set Ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Ie.Visible = True
Ie.Navigate "Site login"


Do While Ie.Busy = True Or Ie.readyState < READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop

Set HTMLDoc = Ie.document

HTMLDoc.getElementById("user_login_name").Value = UserName 'the user name is defined before
HTMLDoc.getElementById("user_password").Value = UserPass 'the password is defined before
LoginButton = Ie.document.getElementsByName("button")
Click = Ie.document.getElementsByTagName
LoginButton.Click

Ie.Navigate "The wanted URL to load fully before the next code activates"

'copy and paste in excel 
Ie.ExecWB 17, 0 '// SelectAll
Ie.ExecWB 12, 2 '// Copy selection

Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A1").Select
Ie.Quit
```

When I run it now I get the user name from login screen

Anything I'm missing?
Thanks in advance for your time

Nik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to keep you waiting, I will close this due to still waiting from our users for feedback(they use this files only once a month). which means I can't confirm if my solution was correct or not. However what I did was tweak the code. and added an if to check the current pages link and added the Ie.readyState < READYSTATE_COMPLETE into the code. it looks like the following:

```
If Ie.LocationURL <> "site link" Then Do While Ie.Busy = True Or Ie.readyState < 
    READYSTATE_COMPLETE DoEvents Loop
End If
```

I do this twice. once for the login page, and the second time.
It seems to work for me(did the data scrape at least 10 times and no error)

Thank you for your time and sorry for the wait.

Answer (score 0):

Put the code below, after second **Ie.Navigate** in your VBA code may help to fix your issue.

```
Do While Ie.Busy = True Or Ie.readyState < READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop
```

Your modified code:

```
Set Ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Ie.Visible = True
Ie.Navigate "Site login"


Do While Ie.Busy = True Or Ie.readyState < READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop

Set HTMLDoc = Ie.document

HTMLDoc.getElementById("user_login_name").Value = UserName 'the user name is defined before
HTMLDoc.getElementById("user_password").Value = UserPass 'the password is defined before
LoginButton = Ie.document.getElementsByName("button")
Click = Ie.document.getElementsByTagName
LoginButton.Click

Ie.Navigate "The wanted URL to load fully before the next code activates"

Do While Ie.Busy = True Or Ie.readyState < READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop

'copy and paste in excel 
Ie.ExecWB 17, 0 '// SelectAll
Ie.ExecWB 12, 2 '// Copy selection

Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A1").Select
Ie.Quit
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Yes i have tried this way as well. However my code is continuing and looping for several times, in which sometimes some of the data doesn't transfer... I'm really baffled...

Comment: Did you try to check with other code examples that wait till page get load? How much data you are trying to copy from the web page? Does this happen with any specific data or random data? If possible then please try to share the sample dummy data. It may help to understand the issue in a better way.

Comment: @Fedo, Is there any progress on this issue? If you had found the solution then please try to post it as an answer and try to mark your own answer as an acceptable answer for this question after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. If the issue still persists then try to refer the suggestions on the thread and let us know about your status for this issue. We will try to provide further suggestions. Thanks for your understanding.